# Вставка содержимого двух таблиц в третью

Tags: sqlite, sql, interbase, firebird, mysql

Добрый день, уважаемы программисты!
Прошу помочь, либо направить в следующей ситуации:
Необходимо из таблиц А(Дата1, ФИО1) и B(Дата2, ФИО2) вывести все данные в таблицу С(Дата, ФИО). Заранее спасибо всем участникам обсуждения.

Использую firebird 2.5

Comment: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-select.html#langrefupd20-union

Comment: @Yura Ivanov а в случае, если названия полей отличаются Union подходит?

Comment: да, названия полей берутся по названиям полей (или псевдонимам) первого запроса. важен только порядок и количество полей, участвующих в запросе. еще хорошо чтоб типы совпадали, для mysql, например, это не обязательно, а для fb это может быть важно.

Comment: Работает, благодарю за помощь!:)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Хотел отсортировать по столбцу - ругается. Сортировка в таком запросе возможна?

Comment: Разобрался:
order by 1 desc
1- номер столбца

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться следующим запросом

```
INSERT INTO C
  SELECT * FROM A
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM B
```

Если необходимо не просто объединить таблицы A и B в таблицу C, а с удалением одинаковых записей, то замените UNION ALL на UNION.